# ReferenceError Html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scripting, referenceerror

I am new to html and scripts. I currently have a very simple html file,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="/Users/MyName1/Desktop/Folder1/testing.js"></script>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph!</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="test()">Ship Package</button>
</body>


</html>
```

and here is my JavaScript Script,

```
function test(){ console.log("hi"); };
```

I tried scr="testing.js" since the file is in the same folder as the html file but it gave me a "ReferenceError Can't find variable test". I then included the whole scr path in the HTML, (even though the html file and the script are in the same folder) but I still get the same "ReferenceError". What is going on? What might I be doing wrong. I am using atom as the IDE btw. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The first thing you should always do is to check if the script is loaded by looking into the network tab in the developer tools of the browser. There you would see that it is not loaded. The reason for this is that you have a typo `scr` instead of `src`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this answer! I didn't know about the network tab! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The script source attribute is incorrect, it should be `src`, not `scr`

Comment: Thank you! I gotta be more careful!

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="/Users/MyName1/Desktop/Folder1/testing.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/MyName1/Desktop/Folder1/testing.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have to explain what you have changed and why.